# How to store query result (a single document) into a variable?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to save a single document into a variable in Mongo JS shell, and manipulate the document (read/write several attributes) for latter operations, but Mongo JS does not seem to put anything into the variable:

```
> a = db.col.find().limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dfccba5fd17fe6a4d0051a"), "a" : 16807, "b" : 475249 }
> a
>
```

Does mongo support the usage? Or was there a mistake?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use `var` like so:

```
> var a = db.col.find().limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dfccba5fd17fe6a4d0051a"), "a" : 16807, "b" : 475249 }
> a
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dfccba5fd17fe6a4d0051a"), "a" : 16807, "b" : 475249 }
```

Doing some testing I have noticed that the `find()` method does appear to be setting the variable to a cursor. In these cases, you lose the variable after the next statement.

```
> var a = db.col.find().limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dfccba5fd17fe6a4d0051a"), "a" : 16807, "b" : 475249 }
> var b = 'test'
> a
>
```

If you need to keep the variable around for longer, try explicitly iterating the variable before setting it using `toArray()`.

```
> var a = db.col.find().limit(1).toArray()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dfccba5fd17fe6a4d0051a"), "a" : 16807, "b" : 475249 }
> var b = 'test'
> a
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("52dfccba5fd17fe6a4d0051a"),
    "a" : 16807,
    "b" : 475249
  }
]
```

Comment: `you lose the variable after the next statement`?? Until you consume all the data in the cursor, it is not lost https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#cursor-behaviors

Answer (score 22):

find returns a cursor. A cursor can only be enumerated once, so once you've enumerated a cursor it has reached the end and will yield no further documents. So in the following example the variable a is assigned a cursor value, and the first time we evaluate "a" in the shell it echoes the results of enumerating the cursor. The second time we evalute "a" it enumerates the cursor again, but this time the cursor is empty so no documents are echoed:

```
> var a = db.test.find().limit(1)
> a
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dfccba5fd17fe6a4d0051a"), "a" : 16807, "b" : 475249 }
> a
>
```

The previous example returns a cursor even though you used limit(1). It's not that "a" loses its value, it still refers to the same cursor, it's just that the cursor it refers to has reached its end.

If you want to read a single document and have the return value be a document instead of a cursor use findOne:

```
> var a = db.test.findOne()
> a
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dfccba5fd17fe6a4d0051a"), "a" : 16807, "b" : 475249 }
> a
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52dfccba5fd17fe6a4d0051a"), "a" : 16807, "b" : 475249 }
>
```

Comment: This is a more straight forward answer than the one by bpruitt-goddard.  If you're only looking for a single document, this will work the way you would expect it to work.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, I kept wondering why my variable only held the value the first time, but the cursor explanation makes total sense.

Answer (score 5):

If you want only one element and want to avoid the "lose the variable" problem described in another answers you can use `findOne()` instead of `find()`:

```
> var doc = db.col.findOne()
```

The `doc` variable set in that way will be permanent.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `find()` is a cursor. To put the document into a variable called "result":

```
var cur = db.col.find().limit(1);
if (cur.hasNext()) {
    var result = cur.next();
    printjson(result);
}
```

Note that `findOne()` returns the result directly, so you can do `var result = db.col.findOne()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `aggregate` or `find` to query, you had better use `var`:

```
var result = db.mycollector.find()
print(result._batch[0]) // get first element
```