# Mongo query result in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is there any way to make a find query with node.js in a MongoDB and save the result in a new variable so it will be used later? All this as a nodejs function outside of the mongo shell. I want my function to return the data as a result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store query result (a single document) into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284857/how-to-store-query-result-a-single-document-into-a-variable)

Comment: you want to store only one document searched from find query or all matched documents like an array??

Comment: I want to save all documents that match my query in a variable like an array yes

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just like this:

```
var result;
db.collection('Collection Name').findOne({'Find Query'}, (err, res) => {
    if(err) throw new Error(err.message, null);
    result = res;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Then do it like this way:

```
var result;
   db.collection('Collection Name').find({'Find Query'}).toArray(function (err, data) {
   if (!err) result = data // result will be an array of objects returned from find.
});
```